# Laravel Excel, Spreadsheet. Problem accessing comments background images (Using Excel generated via Flexcel for .net)

Tags: php, laravel, spreadsheet, laravel-excel

We are using Laravel 7 and Laravel Excel 3.1

When we select a Excel file (generated via Flexcel for .net), when we try obtain the comments' background images, we receive an empty array in the drawing object

We are using Laravel 7, we select the Excel file (generated via Flexcel for .net) and when we try to access the comments in order to get its background image, it returns empty, IT WORKS normally when using a normal Excel (not generated via Flexcel for .net)

In the code below, $file is the uploaded Excel file

```php
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

// Create new Spreadsheet object
$reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xls();
                $reader = $reader->setReadDataOnly(false);
                $sheet = $reader->load($file)->getSheet(0);

$allComments = $sheet->getComments();
              foreach($allComments  as $c => $comment) {
                  if($comment->hasBackgroundImage()){ // return false

                  }
              }
```

We should be able to get the comments' background images but we are getting an empty response, as i mentioned before, the problem occurs ONLY when using an Excel file generated via FLEXCEL, (this file is generated using a Polux hardware)

Comment: That looks like a problem with the file generated by Flexcel. Have you tried opening a support request with the vendor of Flexcel to discuss the issue?